# When to use Thumb rule

Tags: word-usage, indian-english

When should we use the thumb rule word. I got this word from one of my senior resource like. It is the thumb rule you should use this one.

I am having the doubt like shall we use this word for normal talk to when someone is doing something wrong. Or thumb rule is specifically for business.

for example while talking to someone he did something unusual. shall we reply like it is thumb rule that you should not do like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wikipedia: "A rule of thumb is a principle with broad application that is not intended to be strictly accurate or reliable for every situation. It is an easily learned and easily applied procedure for approximately calculating or recalling some value, or for making some determination. Compare this to heuristic..."

If someone says "As rule of thumb, don't do that." He means, doing that thing is not always wrong, but unless you have some specific reason for believing otherwise, it's almost certainly wrong.